# Portrait app shows as Landscape

Tags: android, landscape, portrait

I am an Android developer and have recently made an app for a client. The screen orientation should only be available in portrait, so I have added the option `android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"` to each and every activity in my manifest.

Despite this, my client keeps telling me that the app displays in landscape on her Samsung Tablet. I don't know why this may be, according with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html the orientation should never be landscape. In all of my tests it is displaying correctly (portrait mode), but I don't have access to her device and don't know what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please close your question when you have answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should write this :

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: as I see in the documentation, `android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"` is also a portrait orientation. Why is  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` a better option and how does it solve the problem?